# Php 7.1 ArgumentCountError workarounds?

Tags: php, arguments

As per http://php.net/manual/en/migration71.incompatible.php,

> "Previously, a warning would be emitted for invoking user-defined
>   functions with too few arguments. Now, this warning has been promoted
>   to an Error exception"

In a nutshell, it vas previously possible to call Myfunction(argument) as Myfunction(), while now this throws an exception.

Now, I have a large codebase that doesn't simply call functions like the above example, it even *exploits* that behavior to pass a variable number of arguments to  certain parts of the code, etc.

Is it somehow possible to disable this exception?
Thanks

Comment: Fix the code. You can, for example, pass arrays instead. You can define all the possible calls in the function-declaration, and just change the ones you need to use, and so on and so forth.

Comment: This is what you get for counting on invalid code that didn't fail. *Nevr* count on side effects or weird beahviour. This is what you get when you do.

Comment: @JohnConde not my own code - I think who wrote it was under the impression that it was a feature of php to be able to call functions that way. I frankly more or less thought the same..